# Add raster band statistics to print layout

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer

I would like to add raster band statistics to the print layout. I know something similar is possible to vector layers using "layer_property". Any ideas on how to achieve it on rasters or is it even possible?
so this stats [image]

would be added like this to the map

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

You can use QGIS expressions with the function `raster_statistic()` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#raster-statistic)).

Create a textfield and select `Insert or Edit an Expression…`. Then use an expression like the following one, where you replace `[rasterlayer]` with the name of the rasterlayer and `[band]` with the band:

`raster_statistic('[rasterlayer]',[band],'max')`

Third argument (property) you can choose: min, max, average, standard deviation, range and sum.

[image]

Comment: Removed my answer. Was not aware of existing build-in function... Learned something ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Great, nice to hear that it worked for you. As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 3):

You can acces it with the function `raster_statistic()`.

Here is the process step by step :

1. In your layout, add a label.
2. Type your text to introduce the value "Minimum value is :" and then click on Insert/Edit Expression.
3. In the modal insert expression add the function `raster_statistic(`  then in the help in the middle you have to open `Map Layers` (1) and then to double-click in your raster layer(2). It will add the id of your layer. Then you have to add `,` + `band_id` + `,` + `'minimum')`.

[image]

The result should look like that :

```
raster_statistic( 'sightsmap_georef_0683da82_cb92_4639_a9b1_307348972f1d', 1, 'max')
```

If you want to get other values calculated you can replace min by :

- `max` maximum value
- `avg` average (mean) value
- `stdev` standard deviation of values
- `range` range of values (max - min)
- `sum` sum of all values from raster

Note : you will have the minimum value for all the layer and not only for your zone.

Comment: Thanks Corentin, that solved it